# Send wstring and ptime over MS RPC

Tags: c++, winapi, rpc, idl

Iam using `Microsoft RPC` and i need to transfer my custom structure that have fields of type `std::wstring` and `boost::ptime`. In `idl` there is no such data types. What is best solution to send that struct. In read about serialization with `RPC`. But ms serialization is also based on `idl` file, so i cant define struct in `idl` file with `wstring` and `ptime`.

Comment: Turn wstring into a BSTR I guess. Not sure about ptime but I imagine it is an integer of some sort behind the scenes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IDL has a limited set of basic types, and it can't transfer complete c++ objects, as the receiver might not be written in c++ at all. So, you'll have to do some conversions, but doing so with the types you mention is not very complicated.

Starting with the wstring, here are your options:

1. Pass a c string as `[in, string] wchar_t*`. `wchar_t*` is what you get when calling `std::wstring.c_str()`, so you can easily call the interface without further conversions.
2. Pass a c string [as an array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367081%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) of chars. No real reason to do that, just saying it's possible.
3. Pass a c string as a [BSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b2d7d2c-47af-4389-a6b6-b01b7e915228%28VS.85%29). Now, `BSTR` is not a part of the basic IDL, but an OLE automation extension, widely used in COM. Using it might require [additional configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367073%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). `BSTR` is basically a `wchar_t*`, but with its size at the beginning of the buffer. You can create `BSTR` using `AllocSysString` and free it using `SysFreeString`. Or, you can use ATL's [CComBSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh7x9w3f%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) or the [_bstr_t](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class to manage the BSTRings. Both accept `wchar_t*` in their constructor, so converting the `wstring` won't be a problem.

Now, as for the `ptime`, I'm not really familiar with that type so there might be other options, but I was able to find these two:

1. [Convert the `ptime` to an int64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574647/a-way-to-turn-boostposix-timeptime-into-an-int64), and then use the IDL's [__int64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367391%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) type to pass its value.
2. Use `to_iso_string` to convert the `ptime` to a string, and pass as suggested above (note that `to_iso_string` gets you a regular `std::string` and not a `std::wstring`). On the other side, use `from_iso_string` to get the `ptime` back.

Comment: What do you think about serialize with boost::serialization and send as array of bytes?

Comment: @userbb, I don't know enough about boost::serialization, but sending an array of bytes is definitively a reasonable possibility (and not a hard one to implement). If all you're dealing with are those two arguments, serialization might add an overhead, and make the passed content harder to debug (being an array of bytes), but that might not be a real problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use VARIANT types, which gives you a heap of options in terms of what type of data is passed. In your case, it would be VARIANTs of type VT_BSTR & VT_DATE.

This personally worked well for me because I could then pass SAFEARRAYs, which I could use for passing STL types like std::map.

[Marshaling OLE Data Types:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367073%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Note about above MSDN site: When adding VARIANT types in your IDL, the above link mentions importing "objidl.idl". That still gave me a compile error, and instead importing "oaidl.idl" worked for me.